# Disabling DFP / DoubleClick iFrames

Tags: javascript, google-dfp

In Google DFP (DoubleClick) you are given an ad code to put in your header and another for your body.  When I apply this given ad tag / code to my website, whether its asynchronous or synchronous the ad always displays within an iframe.  I'm wondering how I would disable the iFrame.

**Here is the generated header code via DFP:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var googletag = googletag || {};
googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
(function() {
var gads = document.createElement('script');
gads.async = true;
gads.type = 'text/javascript';
var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
gads.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
'//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
})();
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
googletag.cmd.push(function() {
googletag.defineSlot('/16569348/ad-test-1', [400, 267], 'div-gpt-ad-1362958263281-    0').addService(googletag.pubads());
googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
googletag.enableServices();
});
</script>
```

**Here is the generated body code via DFP:**

```
<!-- ad-test-1 -->
<div id='div-gpt-ad-1362958263281-0' style='width:400px; height:267px;'>
<script type='text/javascript'>
googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1362958263281-0'); });
</script>
</div>
```

**Here is the jsFiddle showcasing this problem (inspect element in google chrome to see iframe):**

http://jsfiddle.net/EptwH/

Again, I'd like to remove the iframe (and keep the image / ad of course)... any help would truly be appreciated. :)

Comment: Many times for us as well, it shows an iframe without really loading an ad, not sure what the solution is for this??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From DFP's website: [link](http://support.google.com/dfp_sb/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=90777)

> When you are using Google Publisher Tags (GPT), your ads will automatically load into iframes.

Comment: NOOOOOOOO!!!! :( that sucks, but at the same time... thanks for the answer.  Do you know of any other way to produce the ads without them going into iframes?  That would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Looks like you can bypass the iframe if you use Google Ad Manager tags http://support.google.com/dfp_sb/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=112649

Comment: do you know if this will make the dimensions (height and width) of the ads changeable on my end?... will I be able to change the width of the ads into a percentage instead of pixels?

Comment: Judging from the documentation in the page I sent you, yes: <script language="JavaScript"> 
    GA_googleAddSlot("ca-pub1", "GizmosUnlimited_HelpCenter_FAQs_ATF_Left_90x90"); 
    GA_googleAddAdSensePageAttr("google_color_bg", "F0F0F0");
    GA_googleAddAdSenseSlotAttr("AdUnitName", "google_color_bg", "F0F0F0");
</script>

Answer (score 2):

We had the same issue, as our goal was to add native ads directly to the host page DOM and not an IFRAME to gain full responsiveness. We came up with a solution, where we're posting the ad content string to the host page using messages. This way there is no more IFRAME.

For details please see http://insights.burda-studios.de/howto-run-fully-responsive-doubleclick-native-ads-without-iframes/

Please note, that we only run house ads using this approach, not any 3rd party ads where this could lead to unexpected behaviours.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working for a digital advertiser and you never should disable iFrames coming from advertising.

ADS can inclusce harmfull scripts, so best would be using Safeframe (frame using src poining to foreign origin) to prevent that.

Also many ad script use `document.write`, and inside their iframe they can do that without problem, would they do that on main window after `document.ready` that would paint your page blank.

Answer (score 1):

Google loads its ads into iframes purposely, this is by design.

This is done because it both allows your page to load faster and to have sand-boxed styles and scripts etc. The render of the page is faster because iframes enable asynchronous loading and rendering of the ad content.

It is possible to "bust" out of the iframe with your ad code if you want, so there is no real disadvantage to the ads being in an iframe, show us an example of what you are trying to do if you have run into a problem

Here is some [more reading](http://support.google.com/dfp_premium/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=183282) to do with this.

Comment: thanks for the help man, i'm running into a problem because I'm trying to change the image ads width to a percentage and not pixels... here's the question explaining everything: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349704/apllying-css-within-an-iframe feel free to help if you want :)

Comment: and do you know how you can "bust" out of the iframe?

Comment: I wish you could send extra parameters to tell it to use percentage widths, then, or add inline styles to the ads within the iframes... If they're going to generate them on the fly anyway, why not give us more fine-tuned control?!   It's like Google has never heard of responsive design...  And, no I DON'T WANT TO SET UP SEPARATE ADS FOR EACH SIZE.  That's great for people who manage  few dozen ads, but I manage HUNDREDS.

Answer (score -1):

Part of your question (whether its asynchronous or synchronous) is wrong in my experience.
Not sure if this has changed or if you failed to let the GPT tags run synchronously, but since I changed to synchronous mode, iframes are no longer used.
See for yourself at [belmodo.tv](http://belmodo.tv)